# Does scaling factor affect discretization?

Tags: discretization, scaling

Suppose I want to solve the below equation numerically.

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=y
$$

I'd like to normalize the space discretization by choosing
$$
a\bar{x}=x
$$
where I assume $\bar{x}$ is unity.
Then the equation is

$$
\frac{1}{a}\frac{dy}{d\bar{x}}=y
\qquad\rightarrow\qquad
\frac{dy}{d\bar{x}}=ay
$$

Thus, my discretization becomes,

1)

$$
\frac{y_{i+1}-y_{i}}{\Delta \bar{x}}=ay
$$

which I don't think it makes sense, since $\Delta \bar{x}$ must be unity, so is

2)

$$
y_{i+1}-y_{i}=ay
$$

right?

Comment: You cannot set the variable $\bar x$ to unity. This is not how scaling works. If $A \leq x \leq B$, then by employing the scaling $a \bar x = x$, you have $A/a \leq \bar x \leq B/a$. The value of $\Delta \bar x$ is independent of the scaling you choose.

Comment: I see... I cannot really set $\bar{x}$ to unity. Then how does $\frac{dy}{d\bar{x}}$ transform into?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{d\bar x} = \frac{dy}{d(x/a)} = a \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: I agree, you cannot set $\bar{x}$ to unity. The purpose of scaling is to collapse solutions together onto one assuming the non-dimensional groups are equal. You can think of $\bar{x}$ as a "scaled" version of the coordinate $x$.